# Change UIView Dynamically

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

Working on cs193p (stanford online videos of iphone programming), I am working on Presence1 exercise 

I am trying to change a UIView which is a subview of another view dynamically.

For those of you who are not aware of the assignment posted on the course, Basically the architecture of the app is as follows:

Nav Controller -> (Root) View Controller - (VC)1 for 1st screen -> calls Detail View controller VC2 for next screen

 Now 1st screen has images and text that I want to load dynamically from my model (which is an object I instantiate in App delegate before pushing the 1st VC on navigation stack. I have defined a parameter in initWithNibName method to pass this model object while initializing the nib for VC1. And I also try to set the image from the model over here and in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear methods. Its not working. 

When I debugged, I saw that the model object being passed is empty.

If you understand the problem, please lemme know what am I missing.

I can post the code if required but will have to post the whole thing to make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed - I was releasing my model object when not required - I was creating a "reference" to one of my objects present in the model (array containing a list of objects) . Note - I was not creating a new object by using alloc/copy. I was then releasing it (even though after the push on to the navigation stack) - Obviously causing my object memory space to get cleared and that reflected in my view controller that was receiving that model object as a parameter in its init method. This was giving the illusion that the object is not getting passed to the view controller!

Lesson Learned earlier - Be very mindful about releasing objects.

Lesson Learned Today - Be very cautious when releasing objects. Don't over release objects - make sure you are releasing an object only if you are calling alloc/copy or retaining it explicitly - memory management 101 - revisited :)

Thanks all for not replying to this question. In a way it forced me to scrutinize my code at a very micro level and I am sure I wont forget this for rest of my life! :)